# Add an edge between nodes which have been labelled as (x,y) coordinates

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I have created a graph on Python using networkx. I have labelled each node as (x,y) as if to create a "coordinate-system" of nodes. If I wanted to add an edge between (x,y) and (p,q) and another from (m,n) to (l,f) how would I do this?

I've tried:

```
g.add_edges_from((x,y),(p,q),(m,n),(l,f))
```

But it's not working.

Would appreciate any help!

Jack

Comment: Do I just have to bracket the individual nodes. I.E. ((x,y),(p,q))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to get the parentheses right:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_edges_from([((1,2),(3,4)),(('a','b'),('c','d'))])

In [4]: list(G.edges())
Out[4]: [((1, 2), (3, 4)), (('c', 'd'), ('a', 'b'))]
```

Comment: Thanks Aric :) Makes sense.